# SignalR using App in browser working well, just not as native app (cordova)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cordova, signalr

I just built a simple "Chat"-App with this guide: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5

> ***Technologies:***
>
> **Server :** ASP.NET MVC 5 + SignalR 2.0
>   **Client :** HTML5/jQuery 2.0.3
>   **Build App :** Cordova

As long as i use it as a regular web-applikation i get my chat working, but if i start compiling it as an app with cordova, nothing happens.

**1)** "ChatHub" [Serverh/C#]

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalRChatMVC.Hubs{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

**2)** "index.html" in path

```
"VisualStudioPath\Projects\SignalRChatMVC\SignalRChatMVC\native\net.Companyname.Projectname\www"
```

.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h2>Chat</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" id="message" />
            <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
            <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
            <ul id="discussion"></ul>
        </div>
        <!--Script references. -->
        <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
        <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
        <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
        <script>
            $(function () {
                // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
                var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
                <!-- $.connection.hub.url = "http://nightcrawler:1234"; -->
                // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
                chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                    // Add the message to the page.
                    $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                        + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
                };
                // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
                $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
                // Set initial focus to message input box.
                $('#message').focus();
                // Start the connection.
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                        // Call the Send method on the hub.
                        chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                        $('#message').val('').focus();
                    });
                });
            });
            // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
            function htmlEncode(value) {
                var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
                return encodedValue;
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

**3)** Calling my mashine in browser like

```
"http://{computername}:1234"
```

works and I can write messages on any browser/tab or device.

**4)** Now i start compiling with cordova:

```
cmd: "{VisualStudioPath}\Projects\SignalRChatMVC\SignalRChatMVC\native\net.{Companyname}.{Projectname}"> cordova build blackberry10

cmd: "{VisualStudioPath}\Projects\SignalRChatMVC\SignalRChatMVC\native\net.{Companyname}.{Projectname}"> cordova run blackberry10
```

and just the homescreen appears.

Does anyone know how to debug native applications and/or has an idea why it is not wroking for native apps? 
Does it maybe has something to do with the blackberry's path, which is not at

```
"{VisualStudioPath}\Projects\SignalRChatMVC\SignalRChatMVC\native\net.{Companyname}.{Projectname}\www"
```

but at

```
"{VisualStudioPath}\Projects\SignalRChatMVC\SignalRChatMVC\native\net.oh22.oh22Push\platforms\blackberry10\www"
```

or maybe it has something to do that there is no real browser anymore being able to use SignalR?

(Should be able to debug on a blackberry directly)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>` is probably wrong.

If a resource isn't bundled with your "index.html" and instead needs to be accessed over the network, you will likely need to reference it with an absolute path. Ex:

```
<script src="http://{computername}:1234/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

You can pregenerate the `/signalr/hubs` script so you can bundle it instead: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy

Lastly, `$.connection.hub.url = "http://nightcrawler:1234";` should be `$.connection.hub.url = "http://nightcrawler:1234/signalr";`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of adding

```
     $.connection.hub.url = "http://{computername}:1234/signalr";
```

Worked very well for me.